# Under Xcode 4.6.2, simulated metrics change can make change of frame of view

Tags: uiview, frame, nib

I have encountered a strange problem,I wish to change the nib file of a UIviewController ,when I step into the **simulated metrics** ,I change the topBar from **none** to **navigationBar**,the frame of subViews (some buttons,or textfield) changed! It seems I cannot use the nib file to rearrange this subview! I tried,but failed.  I don't know why,when I set frame property in the viewDidLoad ,it doesn't work ,I have to change all this in the viewDidAppear.

Can someone give me some idea? (sorry,I only code in the Xcode 4.6.2)